# RestController with ConditionalOnBean fails autowiring the bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this controller and there doesn't exist any bean of AuthenticationService.

```
@ConditionalOnBean({AuthenticationService.class})
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
}
```

When I start the application it fails with this exception.

```
    2017-01-26 15:42:22.806 ERROR 37964 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationService': No qualifying bean of type [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService] found for dependency [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService] found for dependency [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
            at me.factorify.Application.main(Application.java:33) [main/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService] found for dependency [me.factorify.common.security.authentication.AuthenticationService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            ... 19 common frames omitted
```

This doesn't make sense. Why is the controller bean even created? The ComponentScan would instantiate it but I thought that ConditionalOnBean would prevent it from being created.

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure ConditionalOnBean can be used that way. Also, their javadoc says: `it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only`.

Comment: Well, I found out that in simple case this works fine but in a complicated case it fails (not sure why though).

Comment: do you have multiple Spring contexts?

Comment: no, I have just one spring context